# Output of array program

Tags: c, arrays

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {

    int arr[10] = { 11 , [9] = 22 };
    int i;
    arr[13] = 2452;
    arr[10] = 1212;

    for(i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
        printf("arr[%i] %i\n " , i, arr[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output it is generating as follows:

```
arr[0]       11    
arr[1]       0   
arr[2]       0    
arr[3]       0    
arr[4]       0    
arr[5]       0    
arr[6]       0
arr[7]       0    
arr[8]       0    
arr[9]       22    
arr[10]      10    
arr[11]     -1216806924   
arr[12]     0   
arr[13]     2452    
arr[14]    -1218431789
```

output of arr [10] and arr [13] I'm unable to understand.

Comment: The program has undefined behavior because it accesses elements that are outside the bounds of `arr`. Knowing why your program behaves in a particular way might be useful, but generally your time will be better spent fixing your code than figuring out why your existing code behaves in a particular way.

Answer (score 2):

arr[] size is 10, so arr[0] to [9] values are valid.   everything else is rubish, you are accesing memory out of bounds

Comment: so it is just a coincidence that 2452 is assigned to  a [13]?

Comment: It was not "assigned" to `a[13]`, it was the value that happened to be there. Local variables on the stack are **not** initialised, but you initialised the 10 elements.

Comment: It's not coincidence, but it's also not valid.  a[13] may exist as an actual chunk of memory (and in your case it does), which means you can set its value, but there is no guarantee it will keep its value, and no guarantee you haven't accidentally changed some other variable's value.

Comment: In fact you've got an example of that in your code.  Notice how arr[10] = 10, even though you set it to 1212?  That's because arr[10] is out of the array bounds, and actually points to `i`.  Print out the value of `i` just before the for loop and you'll see it's got an initial value of 1212.

Comment: @Darryl that i understood that both arr[10] and **i** share the same memory address

Answer (score 0):

I will try to explain. It seems that the compiler placed local variables in the stack in the following way as they were declared

```
int arr[10] = { 11 , [9] = 22 };
int i;
```

In this case object `int i` occupies memory that corresponds to `arr + 10` (actual elements of the array occupy memory from arr + 0 to arr + 9 inclusively)
Thus when in the loop you output `arr[10]` then in fact you output object `i` that in this moment is equal naturally to 10.
That is at first you set `i` to 1212 (arr[10] = 1212;) and then in the loop the variable is overwritten  i and arr[10[ share the same memory.

As for arr[13] then the program outputs its value as it was set before the loop.

Of course your program has undefined behaviour because you are overwritting memory beyond the array.

Comment: yup  i  and  arr[10]  do share the same memory address.

Comment: regarding  a[13]  shouldn't the value be assigned to  a[14] ?

Comment: @vaibhav agnihotri Why? You explicitly set the value of arr[13] yourself: arr[13] = 2452;